# Variable number of inputs with Django forms possible?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is it possible to have a variable number of fields using django forms?

The specific application is this:

A user can upload as many pictures as they want on the image upload form. Once the pictures are uploaded they are taken to a page where they can give the pictures a name and description. The number of pictures will depend on how many the user has chosen to upload.

So **how do I get django to generate a form using a variable number of input fields** (which could be passed as an argument if necessary)?

**edit:** a few things have changed since the [article mentioned in jeff bauer's answer](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) was written.

Namely this line of code which doesn't seem to work:

```
# BAD CODE DO NOT USE!!!
return type('ContactForm', [forms.BaseForm], { 'base_fields': fields })
```

So here is what I came up with...

## The Answer I used:

```
from tagging.forms import TagField
from django import forms

def make_tagPhotos_form(photoIdList):
    "Expects a LIST of photo objects (ie. photo_sharing.models.photo)"

    fields = {}

    for id in photoIdList:
        id = str(id)

        fields[id+'_name'] = forms.CharField()
        fields[id+'_tags'] = TagField()
        fields[id+'_description'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    return type('tagPhotos', (forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```

note tagging is not part of django, but it is free and very useful. check it out: [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/)

Comment: I don't get how all that is working together : do you have some code or git repo with a more complet example ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create forms dynamically in Django.  You can even mix and match dynamic fields with normal fields.

```
class EligibilityForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EligibilityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # dynamic fields here ...
        self.fields['plan_id'] = CharField()
    # normal fields here ...
    date_requested = DateField()
```

For a better elaboration of this technique, see James Bennett's article: **So you want a dynamic form?**

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/

Answer (score 7):

If you run

```
python manage.py shell
```

and type:

```
from app.forms import PictureForm
p = PictureForm()
p.fields
type(p.fields)
```

you'll see that p.fields is a SortedDict. you just have to insert a new field. Something like

```
p.fields.insert(len(p.fields)-2, 'fieldname', Field())
```

In this case it would insert before the last field, a new field. You should now adapt to your code.

Other alternative is to make a for/while loop in your template and do the form in HTML, but django forms rock for some reason, right?

Comment: Almost gave you the accepted answer, jeff's was just a little bit clearer (the link helped a lot)

Answer (score 7):

Use either multiple forms (django.forms.Form not the  tag)

```
class Foo(forms.Form):
    field = forms.Charfield()

forms = [Foo(prefix=i) for i in xrange(x)]
```

or add multiple fields to the form dynamically using self.fields.

```
class Bar(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, fields, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in xrange(fields):
            self.fields['my_field_%i' % i] = forms.Charfield()
```