# Django: creating a text with gaps for input

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a text on my website, where the gaps, in which the user can input a word (like the c-tests for learning language) are dynamically created depending on the text that the function gets from the database (not yet implemented).

My idea was it to create a formset in which each label is different depending on a variable I give it.

Here is my views.py

```
def ctest(request):

    c_test_tokens, gaps, tokenindexe = generate_c_test(beispieltext())

    # EXAMPLE
    # NOT WORKING ON POST REQUEST YET
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CTestform(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        ctestformset = formset_factory(CTestform, extra=len(gaps))
        return render(request, 'ctest.html', {'form': ctestformset})
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class CTestform(forms.Form):

    hello = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '5'}),
                          required=False, label='hello', label_suffix='')
```

Is this approach fine and how do I give the form a list with each element being the label for each gap, or should I search for an alternative?

**EDIT:**

Ok I tried the things on this site [Variable number of inputs with Django forms possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411761/variable-number-of-inputs-with-django-forms-possible)

My forms.py now has the function

```
    def creategaps(self, c_test_tokens, gaps, tokenindexes):
        wordsbeforegap = ''
        gaps = {}
        iteratorforgaps = 0
        for i in (0, len(c_test_tokens)-1):
            if '#GAP#' not in c_test_tokens[i]:
                wordsbeforegap = wordsbeforegap + c_test_tokens[i]

            else:
                gaps[iteratorforgaps] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '5'}),
                                           required=False, label=wordsbeforegap, label_suffix='')
                wordsbeforegap = ''

        return type('test', (forms.BaseForm,), {'base_fields': gaps})
```

I tried to call the function from views.py but it doesnt create any form.
Here is the else statement in views.py

```
    else:
    form = CTestform.creategaps("test", c_test_tokens, gaps, tokenindexe)
    return render(request, 'ctest.html', {'form': form})
```

Why doesnt it work?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying a gap? Many input field you mean? What is your purpose on doing this?

Comment: I want to create a text where some words are cut in half and in the second half the word gets replaced by a gap where the user can input words in it to complete the word (like the c-tests for learning a language). The number of gaps are created dynamically depending on the text.