# Is there a way to pass a list to determine fields in a django form?

Tags: python, django

I have a list determined by an admin for which fields the user should be able to fill out. I have tried passing a subset of my fields into the fields variable in my forms.py but all the fields are still rendered in the template.

**forms.py**

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):

    myList = ['field1']

    field1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    field2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = myList
```

Im just rendering my form with `{{ form }}` in my html. I dont get any errors but my app renders all the fields instead of just the ones in my list

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/411761/12744275 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code below :

```
class myModel(models.Model):  # Your Model
    field1 = models.CharField( .. )
    field2 = models.CharField( .. )


class myForm(forms.ModelForm):  # Your Form Model
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ['field1']
        widgets = {
            'field1': forms.TextInput( attrs={'class': 'form-control'} )
        }
```

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: This works but its not as dynamic as I need it. I need an admin to be able to go into the admin panel and check which boxes each user will see on his form. 200 users and 200 hundred different forms.